# How plug star-rating plugin to html document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a star rating table which calculating average number of all star columns using krajee plugin.But i have little bug here.Everything work great in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cheapskate/dpnrgdk3/13/) but isnt work in docs.Have a bug with snippets.When i use  [local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YyLt.jpg) `star-rating.js` file the function `ww()` isnt work.When i use cdn like in jsfiddle `<script src="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/js/star-rating.js"></script>`  everything work except   [stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJw0r.jpg) isnt display.Please help me figure out.

```js
  $("#question1").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars:10,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.5,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });

$('#question1').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
ww();
});


  $("#question3").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars: 10,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.5,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });


$('#question3').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
ww();
});


  $("#question2").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars: 10,
    min: 0,
    max:10,
    step: 0.5,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });


$('#question2').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
ww();
});


  $("#question4").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars: 10,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.5,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });

$('#question4').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
ww();
});
```

```css
/*!
 * @copyright &copy; Kartik Visweswaran, Krajee.com, 2013 - 2015
 * @version 3.5.4
 *
 * A simple yet powerful JQuery star rating plugin that allows rendering
 * fractional star ratings and supports Right to Left (RTL) input.
 *
 * For more JQuery/Bootstrap plugins and demos visit http://plugins.krajee.com
 * For more Yii related demos visit http://demos.krajee.com
 */
.rating-loading {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    background: transparent url('../img/loading.gif') top left no-repeat;
    border: none;
}
/*
 * Stars
 */
.rating-fa {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    padding-left: 1px;
}

.rating-fa .rating-stars:before {
    padding-left: 1px;
}

.rating-gly {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}

.rating-gly-star {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-lg .rating-gly-star, .rating-lg .rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.rating-xl .rating-gly-star, .rating-xl .rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-active {
    cursor: default;
}

.rating-disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.rating-uni {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.rating-container {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #e3e3e3;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rating-container:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
}

.rating-container .rating-stars {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fde16d;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.rating-container .rating-stars:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.rating-container-rtl {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fde16d;
}

.rating-container-rtl:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.rating-container-rtl .rating-stars {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #e3e3e3;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.rating-container-rtl .rating-stars:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
}

/**
 * Rating sizes
 */
.rating-xl {
    font-size: 4.89em;
}

.rating-lg {
    font-size: 3.91em;
}

.rating-md {
    font-size: 3.13em;
}

.rating-sm {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

.rating-xs {
    font-size: 2em;
}

/**
 * Clear rating button
 */
.star-rating .clear-rating, .star-rating-rtl .clear-rating {
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 60%;
}

.clear-rating-active {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.clear-rating-active:hover {
    color: #843534;
}

.star-rating .clear-rating {
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/**
 * Caption
 */
.star-rating .caption, .star-rating-rtl .caption {
    color: #999;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 55%;
}

.star-rating .caption {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.star-rating-rtl .caption {
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/**
 * Print
 */
@media print {
    .rating-container, .rating-container:before , .rating-container-rtl .rating-stars, .rating-container-rtl .rating-stars:before {
        color: #f3f3f3!important;
    }
    
    .star-rating .clear-rating, .star-rating-rtl .clear-rating {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/css/star-rating.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/js/star-rating.js"></script>


<form id="fld">
  <input id="question1" class="rating rating-loading">
  <input id="question2">
  <input id="question3">
  <input id="question4">
</form>
<div class="entirety">
  <p class="amount">Общая оценка
    <p id='d'>0</p>
</div>

<script>
  function ww() {
    var oi = document.getElementById('fld').getElementsByTagName('input');

    var val = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < oi.length; i++) {

      val += +oi[i].value;
    };
    val = val / oi.length;
    document.getElementById('d').textContent = val;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a quick look at your code as I got working on my local side.

Here is a few reason that why you could not get star on this localhost web

1) No body and head in the HTML files.
2) No Meta Tag 
3) missing slash / in the CSS files along with rel stylesheet like you wrote, as first line with no slash / at the end but you did put it on the second line.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/css/star-rating.css" />
```

Here is a code I wrote in the HTML

```
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/css/star-rating.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/js/star-rating.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="fld">
   <input id="question1" class="rating rating-loading">
   <input id="question2" class="rating rating-loading">
   <input id="question3" class="rating rating-loading">
   <input id="question4" class="rating rating-loading">
</form>
<div class="entirety">
  <p class="amount">Rate it 
    <p id='d'>0</p>
</div>
</body>


<script>
  function ww() {
    var oi = document.getElementById('fld').getElementsByTagName('input');

    var val = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < oi.length; i++) {

      val += +oi[i].value;
    };
    val = val / oi.length;
    document.getElementById('d').textContent = val;
  }
</script>
```

I hope it will help you and resolved this issue, your JS and CSS are fine. just mistake on the head tag.

Comment: thank you for answer ill check you right now and accept youre answer .

Comment: If it working on your side then don't forget tick answer. it might help for someone to read it in the future.

Comment: this code working on youre side? O.o how it possible :( it isnt work

Comment: it worked thank u i just copy ur head and paste in my head thank u one more time